# Extraordinarily long names in Modern Warfare?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Every now and then I run into people with names that extend off the screen in Modern Warfare 2.  How can I get a name like that?  Steam seems to limit the number of characters I can have when I try.

Comment: Are you sure that it's Steam doing the limiting? I see long names pretty frequently in L4D2 and TF2. (also extend off the screen from where? The centre? The right?)

Comment: @Macha Maybe the 'hack' (I'm using the word VERY liberally here) is with steam itself?

Comment: Can you give an example of a long name?

Comment: Just to clarify, it is a possibility that Steam user names are what is actually very long?

Comment: @Robb There is a limitation in Steam for how long you can make your name.

Comment: @Mechko is the text by any chance smaller for these long names?

Comment: @Robb no it is not.  At least not in-game

Comment: @Mechko every now and then I poke around the internet for an answer.  There's nothing on this! I personally didn't see any long names in TF2 that I recall.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's any secret to it at all. The font is proportional and so it's important to use wide characters. To produce this screenshot I simply entered as many <kbd>G</kbd> in Steam settings as was possible. There are probably wider characters.

[image]

Indeed, the letter <kbd>W</kbd> extends off-screen without having to mouseover the name.

[image]

Comment: That would explain why the people who have it have only one character in their name... :-p

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to achieve what you want, you would need some 3rd party enabler which would be against the game's ToS, I'm sure.  I had a suspicion that the Developer's Console would provide some name change abilities(which it may) but unless some things have changed, it seems even enabling the Developer's Console is even considered a ['hack'](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1107670&page=2).

Comment: it used to be you could simply type in 'name <new unnecessarily long name for the current game you are playing>' to change your name, not sure if this is the case with MW2 or not

Comment: in the dev console or just the chat area?

Comment: Mechko could try this out.  I'll glady take down my answer if that works.

Comment: Modern Warfare 2 doesn't have an accessible console as far as I know...

Comment: Yea, my answer was more from the Counter-Strike side of things...not MW2.  I somewhat assumed that Robb knew what he was talking about when he mentioned an available developer's console :p